# Is there a fundamental obstacle to Rails making `ActiveRecord.where` type-safe for `belongs_to` conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

(Note: This isn't a real problem that I have, just something I was wondering about. I'm not looking for workarounds or implementations).

Suppose I have these three models:

**a.rb**

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :b
  belongs_to :c
end
```

**b.rb**

```
class B < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**c.rb**

```
class C < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I call `A.where(b: foo)`, but I've made a mistake and `foo` is an object of type `C`. Instead of an exception, Rails dutifully looks for an `A` which has a `B` with `foo`'s ID. If I'm unlucky, it might even find something.

I'm curious about why Rails doesn't do this type-checking for me. The behavior I'd expect is this: if I specify a hash condition in `.where` with a key equal to the name of a relation defined on my model, whose value is some ActiveRecord object, check that the class of the ActiveRecord object is equal to the `class_name` of the relation and throw an exception if not.

Is there a fundamental obstacle to doing so? (i.e. it's Turing-complete). Or was this a design decision?

Comment: Consider `class D < B; end` should that thrown an error?

Comment: @Kris: Good point! No, it certainly shouldn't throw an error -- instead of checking for equality with `class_name` can we constantize it and check `is_a?` instead?

Comment: Ruby has always been more about duck typing than explicit type checks which makes sense since it is a weakly typed dynamic language. There is nothing stopping you from tossing a bunch of type checks in everywhere. Its just not how we roll.

Comment: In this particular case it would be a PITA since `.where` would need to look at the association reflections to check what the column should point to.